# Как вытащить из SQL-запроса 1 переменную через PDO

Tags: php, mysql

```
$db = Db::getConnection();
    $result = $db->query($sql = "SELECT p.*, cat.name AS category_name
                                FROM products AS p 
                                JOIN category AS cat
                                ON p.category_id  = cat.id
                                WHERE cat.link = '{$category}'");
    $i = 0;
    $cat_name = $result->fetch()['category_name'];
    $productList = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $productList[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
        $productList[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
        $productList[$i]['link'] = $row['link'];
        $productList[$i]['discount_price'] = $row['discount_price'];
        $i++;
    }
    array_unshift($productList, $cat_name);

    return $productList;
}
```

Есть такой запрос. Этот запрос выдает все данные из таблицы products, а также cat.name. Проблема заключается в том, что при выносе category_name в отдельную переменную `$cat_name = $result->fetch()['category_name'];` получается полный бред, ибо он почему-то выносит не только category_name, но и всю первую запись. Т.е. если убрать в данной функции `$cat_name = $result->fetch()['category_name'];`, то выборка будет идти так:

> строка1 - строка2 -строка3

Но если ее оставить, то выборка пойдет со второй строки из таблицы, т.е.

> строка2 - строка3 и т.д.

Вопрос - как вытащить переменную category_name, не трогая при этом первую строку из запроса? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: например перенести ее получение внутрь цикла. по `if($i==0)`

Comment: или выполнить fetch до цикла, получить переменную, а цикл переделать на do-while

Comment: @Mike видимо, я что-то не понимаю...можете расписать по-подробнее, как это должно выглядеть?

UPD: все сделал, огромное спасибо! Вставил if в цикл
Добавьте это как ответ, чтобы я закрыл вопрос, Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: ну мне кажется это каким то костыльным решением. может спецы по php еще что подскажут ...

Answer (score 0):

Команда fetch производит выборку строки, а не столбца. Выполняя её первый раз вы выбираете первую строку (никак не столбец), при этом указатель смещается на следующую строку (поэтому следующий запрос вам выдаёт данные второй строки).

В вашем случае не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите получить в итоге. Если вам нужно получить массив содержащий категории это можно сделать в одном цикле, следующим образом:

```
db = Db::getConnection();
    $result = $db->query($sql = "SELECT p.*, cat.name AS category_name
                                FROM products AS p 
                                JOIN category AS cat
                                ON p.category_id  = cat.id
                                WHERE cat.link = '{$category}'");
    $i = 0;
    $cat_name    = array();
    $productList = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $cat_name[$i]               = $row['category_name'];
        $productList[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
        $productList[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
        $productList[$i]['link']  = $row['link'];
        $productList[$i]['discount_price'] = $row['discount_price'];
        $i++;
    }
    array_unshift($productList, $cat_name);

    return $productList;
}
```

В этом случае вы получите массив $cat_name содержащий список категорий. Т.е. получите ожидаемый вами результат работы скрипта.

PS. Кстати $i можно вообще исключить, т.к. добавление нового элемента массива без явного указания индекса [] будет означать его автоматический автоинкремент.

Comment: Ого, спасибо огромное, одно сообщение, а в голове много чего на место встало)
В итоге хочу получить следующее: массив, где будет храниться название категории, а также продукты из этой категории.
Правильно понял, что можно писать просто $productList[]['link']? Т.е. вариант, который был предложен в комментарии под записью - не совсем правильный?

Comment: Да, можно просто писать $productList[]['link'], честно говоря я не совсем понял, что имел ввиду автор комментария про $i == 0, поэтому не готов сказать корректный это комментарий или нет.

Категория у вас у всех продуктов одна и та же? Или может быть разная?

Comment: Разная) Это страница вывода товаров определенной категории

Comment: Если конкретно в этом запросе везде категории одинаковые, то можно использовать вариант с `$i == 0` чтобы избавиться от массива в `$cat_name[$i]` , ну или можно написать:
`$cat_name  = $row['category_name'];`
тогда эта переменная каждый раз будет переопределяться, но т.к. категории одинаковые это по сути не будет иметь значения.